# Replace cell values in df based on complex condition

Tags: pandas

**Hello friends,**

- I would like to iterate trough all the numeric columns in the df (in a generic way).
- For each unique df["Type"] group in each numeric column:

  Replace all values that are greater than each column mean + 2 standard
  deviation values with "nan"

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['Test1']=[7,1,2,5,1,90]
df['Test2']=[99,10,13,12,11,87]
df['Type']=['Y','X','X','Y','Y','X']
```

---

Sample df:

```
PRODUCT Test1   Test2   Type
A       7       99      Y
B       1       10      X
C       2       13      X
A       5       12      Y
B       1       11      Y
C       90      87      X
```

---

Expected output:

```
RODUCT  Test1   Test2    Type
    A       7       nan     Y
    B       1       10      X
    C       2       13      X
    A       5       12      Y
    B       1       11      Y
    C       nan     nan     X
```

Comment: Can you please post input and expected output data in text form or machine readable format?

Comment: @anky_91 I see what you did there. OP just to make sure, are you requiring +2std or an absolute value of 2std (-2std/+2std)?

Comment: @Celius Stingher
+2std only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logically, it can go like this:

```
test_cols = ['Test1', 'Test2']

# calculate mean and std with groupby
groups = df.groupby('Type')
test_mean = groups[test_cols].transform('mean')
test_std = groups[test_cols].transform('std')

# threshold
thresh = test_mean + 2 * test_std

# thresholding
df[test_cols] = np.where(df[test_cols]>thresh, np.nan, df[test_cols])
```

However, from your sample data set, `thresh` is:

```
        Test1       Test2
0   10.443434  141.707912
1  133.195890  123.898159
2  133.195890  123.898159
3   10.443434  141.707912
4   10.443434  141.707912
5  133.195890  123.898159
```

So, it wouldn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this through a groupby and transform:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Product'] = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C']
df['Test1']=[7,1,2,5,1,90]
df['Test2']=[99,10,13,12,11,87]
df['Type']=['Y','X','X','Y','Y','X']
df = df.set_index('Product')

def nan_out_values(type_df):
    type_df[type_df > type_df.mean() + 2*type_df.std()] = np.nan
    return type_df

df[['Test1', 'Test2']] = df.groupby('Type').transform(nan_out_values)
```